#  Hold or Wait while Coroutine finishes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

In the example below, how can I get FinishFirst() to complete first before running DoLast(), while still retaining the 'public void StartPage()' signature?

I'm trying to avoid making "StartPage()" return an IEnumerator as that would force me to change it in the interface. It would be great if my Interface for StartPage() supported both IEnumerator and Void without needing to implement both.

```
public void StartPage()
{
    print("in StartPage()");
    StartCoroutine(FinishFirst(5.0f));
    DoLast();
    print("done");

}    

IEnumerator FinishFirst(float waitTime)
{
    print("in FinishFirst");        
    yield return WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
    print("leave FinishFirst");
}    

void DoLast()
{
    print("do after everything is finished");
}
```

Comment: I don't believe System.Threading.Tasks are allowed by default, and in trying to use BeginInvoke Unity can't seem to find the definition for IAsyncResult...

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# / Unity :" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0):

Use of a lock-object should work:

```
object lockObject = new object();

public void StartPage()
{
    print("in StartPage()");
    StartCoroutine(FinishFirst(5.0f));
    DoLast();
    print("done");

}    

IEnumerator FinishFirst(float waitTime)
{
    lock(lockObject)
    {
        print("in FinishFirst");        
        yield return WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        print("leave FinishFirst");
    }
}    

void DoLast()
{
    lock(lockObject)
    {
        print("do after everything is finished");
    }
}
```

Comment: lock-object didn't seem to wait while the coroutine finishes, thanks though...I learned a new keyword! ;-)

Comment: Ok, so you need to sleep a little too, so FinishFirst gets a chance to lock the object.

Comment: lock() is a simplification of using semaphores. Read in the help how you can set the lock in the main loop and clear it in FinishFirst instead. Then you can just wait for the lock.

Comment: Thanks Mattias, sorry was away for the weekend.  I would need to put for example, "System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);" after the "lock(lockObject)" in the FinishFirst() method correct? and can you point me to where in the Unity help that information is located? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but if I understand the question correctly, something like this works. DoLast() will run at the end of the co-routine.

```
IEnumerator FinishFirst(float waitTime)
{
    print("in FinishFirst");        
    yield return WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
    print("leave FinishFirst");
    DoLast();
}
```

I use a lot of similar code inside co-routines to clean and kill the routine if another one was created when this one is running (mainly for typed-text dialog boxes where the text might change at any time).