# Declare a function supporting both Void and IEnumerator

Tags: c#, void, ienumerator

I was wondering if there is a way to declare a method (in an interface for example) that supports the use of IEnumerator and Void, without the need to implement both in the subclasses?

```
public void Start()
public IEnumerator Start()
```

this is related to my other question:  [Hold or Wait while Coroutine finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731295/c-sharp-unity-hold-or-wait-while-coroutine-finishes)

i noticed in the Unity context, the default `Start()` method seems to allow for both.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# : " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Why do you need "void" version? Just not using result is perfectly fine...

Comment: sorry for the prefix...thought it would clarify/make more specific my question.

in my other question, I wanted a general void function to call a coroutine and wait for the coroutine to finish before continuing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that because those methods would have the same signature and the CSC woudn't be able to figure out which method should be statically bound for each call. e.g.:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int FooMethod()
    {
        return 1;
    }
    public void FooMethod()
    {
        return;
    }
    public string FooMethod()
    {
        return "foo";
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    TestClass test = new TestClass();

    Console.WriteLine(test.FooMethod()); // which FooMethod should be called here?
}
```

A method's return type is not considered as part of its signature. What you can do is overload the same method with a different signature to return a different type. Also, in the case of an additional method that differs only in returning `void`, you can always choose not to use the result returned by the original method.

The case with interfaces is similar. when a class implements an interface it is agreeing to a protocol, that it implements that interface's behaviour which is what consumers of your class expect. So you cannot partly agree with an interface. Although you can throw a `NotImplementedException` in your implementations you have to at least *define* all members, which leads to the same problem mentioned in the above example: the C# compiler will not be able to statically bind your method calls and your code will fail to compile.

You can solve your problem by reconsidering your design.

Comment: I understand the ambiguity the compiler has in determining which function.

I'm trying to avoid forcing a class implementing the Interface to have to write an empty function. 

I can't seem to think of a general redesign that would allow me to do what I need in the referring question (which is wait while the IEnumerator function completes)

Comment: If you implement your method well it won't DO anything until the referer iterates over the IEnumerator. Thus the method will be as fast as the imaginary void-method.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no.

The closest you could get to this is using generics, however that would not work for a void, sorry.

```
public T Start()
```

Answer (score 2):

One function name + combination of parameters can only be declared once, thus can only have one output.